# Data Structure for Text Classification Task

Tags: python, text, sparse-matrix

I'm doing a text classification / tagging task and I would like to ask what kind of data structure would serve me best.  The training data set I have is about 4 gigs (after some cleaning, but should be even smaller if I discard the rare words) with 6 million documents.  Each document has 4 fields:

1. Document ID
2. Title
3. Body
4. Tags (as a string, e.g. "apple sql-server linux". This represents three tags, separated by a space.  Documents can have 1-5 tags)

I've just finished the cleaning phase (stemming, stop words etc etc) and I'm about to convert them into a TF-IDF word vector with scikit so the output is a scipy sparse matrix.  I would like to keep the Title and Body as two vectors and combine them at a later stage when I decide on what weighting to give the Title.  The Title and Body are sparse vectors, but they are built with the same dictionary so have the same no. of columns.

What is the best way to represent this information?  I come from R so I'm just used to storing things in data.tables / data frames but that doesn't seem very applicable for text classification and sparse matrices.  One thing I thought about doing is creating my own "Document" class and just have a list of these objects to represent the corpus.  I don't think this is very efficient, since I would probably want to do something like `return all docs with the Tag apple`.

ML algorithms I plan to run are k-means clustering, kNN, Naive Bayes and possibly SVM.  There will probably others that I haven't thought about yet.

I'm new to Python and text classification - any help is greatly appreciated and I am especially interested in ppl who have done it before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of [`dictionary`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) objects. A list of keep all the documents, and a dictionary to keep all the information regarding the document.